# Radio buttons in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I grouped four radio buttons on the radiogroup.  There are create file, create folder, delete and copy radio buttons, but I am having a problem with the copy button.

It's mostly working alright but the message window (saying where the file was copied to the hard drive) is not closing.  How can i make it close?  Or is there a way to refresh the radio buttons?

This is a homework problem.

Here is my code:

```
 procedure TForm1.btnsubmitClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i,j,k,t,index,pred,delp,temp,temp2:integer;
begin
if rbtncreatefolder.checked = true then
     begin
    if (length(edit3.Text)>0) and (edit3.Text<>'..') then begin
        if (VS>=3)   then  begin
        if sush(true,nk1,edit3.Text) then  begin

        i:=tabld[nk1].nach;
        while fat[i]<>1024 do i:=fat[i];
        fat[i]:=freep(i);
        tabld[fat[i]].name:=edit3.Text;
       tabld[fat[i]].format:='';
        tabld[fat[i]].tip:=true;
        fat[fat[i]]:=1024;
        k:=freep(fat[i]);
        tabld[fat[i]].nach:=k;
        tabld[k].name:='.';
        tabld[k].tip:=true;
        tabld[k].nach:=fat[i];
        t:=freep(k);
        fat[k]:=t;
        tabld[t].name:='..';
        tabld[t].tip:=true;
        tabld[t].nach:=nk1;
        fat[t]:=1024;
        tabld[fat[i]].razmer:=0;
        tabld[i].razmer:=tabld[i].razmer+1;
      reload;
        end
        end
        else
            showmessage('Not enough free memory!');
    end
    else
      showmessage('Incorrect data or absent!');
end
else if rbtncreatefile.Checked = true then
  begin
    if (length(edit3.Text)>0) and (length(edit4.Text)>0)then begin
        if strtoint(edit4.Text)<32*VS then begin
         if  sush(false,nk1,edit3.Text) then begin

        i:=tabld[nk1].nach;
        while fat[i]<>1024 do i:=fat[i];
        fat[i]:=freep(i);
        tabld[fat[i]].name:=edit3.Text;
        tabld[fat[i]].format:=copy(edit3.Text,length(edit3.Text)-4,3);
        tabld[fat[i]].tip:=false;
        tabld[fat[i]].razmer:=strtoint(edit4.Text);
        if radiobutton1.Checked then
             tabld[fat[i]].format:='txt'
        else
             tabld[fat[i]].format:='bin';
        tabld[fat[i]].nach:=freep(fat[i]);
        k:=tabld[fat[i]].nach;
        fat[fat[i]]:=1024;
        for j:=1 to (tabld[fat[i]].razmer-9) div 32 do begin
            fat[k]:=freep(k);
            k:=fat[k];
        end;
        fat[k]:=1024;
        reload;
        end
        end
        else
            showmessage('Not enough free memory!');
    end
    else
        showmessage('You did not enter name and \ or File Size!');
end
 else if rbtndelete.checked = true then
  begin
if listbox1.ItemIndex>=0 then begin
    if listbox1.Items.Strings[listbox1.ItemIndex]<>'dir>..' then begin
    pred:=tabld[nk1].nach;
    index:=tabld[nk1].nach;
    for i:=0 to  listbox1.ItemIndex do begin
       index:=fat[index];
       if i>0 then
          pred:=fat[pred];
    end;
    delP:=index;
    fat[pred]:=fat[index];
    if tabld[index].tip then begin
    showmessage('directory "'+tabld[index].name+'" and all its subdirectories have been deleted!');
        rekur(tabld[delp].nach);
        fat[delp]:=0;
        fat[tabld[delp].nach]:=0;
    end
    else begin
    showmessage('file "'+tabld[index].name+'.'+tabld[index].format+'" was removed!');
        i:=tabld[index].nach;
        while fat[i]<>1024 do begin
         j:=i;
         i:=fat[i];
         fat[j]:=0;
        end;
        fat[i]:=0;
        fat[index]:=0;
        end;
        reload;
    end
    else
      showmessage('You can not delete this directory!');
end
else
    showmessage('You did not select the folder to delete!');
end

else if rbtncopy.checked = true then
   begin
if listbox1.ItemIndex>=0 then begin
    if listbox1.Items.Strings[listbox1.ItemIndex]<>'dir>..' then begin
        index:=tabld[nk1].nach;
        for i:=0 to  listbox1.ItemIndex do
          index:=fat[index];
        if tabld[index].tip then begin
          showmessage('directory "'+tabld[index].name+'" and all its subdirectories are copied to the directory "'+edit2.text+'" !');
          temp:=nk1;
          nk1:=nk2;
          edit3.Text:=tabld[index].name;
          btnsubmit.Click;
          temp2:=tabld[nk2].nach;
                while   (fat[temp2]<>1024) and (tabld[temp2].name<>tabld[nk1].name) do temp2:=fat[temp2];
          rekurC(fat[tabld[index].nach],temp2);
          nk1:=temp;
        end
        else begin
          showmessage('file "'+tabld[index].name+'.'+tabld[index].format+'" was copied to directory "'+edit2.Text+'"!');
          temp:=nk1;
          nk1:=nk2;
          edit3.Text:=tabld[index].name;
          edit4.Text:=inttostr(tabld[index].razmer);
          btnsubmit.Click;
          nk1:=temp;
        end
    end
    else
      showmessage('This directory may not be copied!');
end
else
    showmessage('You have not picked anything up to copy!');
            reload;

end

else
 showmessage('select an operator please');
end;
```

Comment: What is `sush`, `tabld` and how is `tabld` filled, `freep`, `fat` and how is `fat` filled, `reload`; Two hints, definitely improve your formatting, I'm not wondering you're lost in this code, don't use `pred` as a variable name, there is also a [`Pred`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Pred) function.

Comment: Is this a FAT32 filesystem simulated in memory for a homework assignment?

Comment: You don't have to write lines like 'if rbtncreatefolder.checked = true'; it would be enough to write 'if rbtncreatefolder.checked'. Not that I would use this construct either: use the radiogroup.itemindex value in a 'case' statement.

Comment: Some high level advice. 1. Break the code into separate functions. Each top level if block should be a separate routine. 2. Fix your indentation. 3. Separate the code that access the UI from the code that does the work. 4. Use more descriptive variable names. 5. Find commonality in the code and extract that into separate methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right at the end of this rather gruesome event handler is this code:

```
showmessage('file "'+tabld[index].name+'.'+tabld[index].format+
  '" was copied to directory "'+edit2.Text+'"!');
...//do stuff
btnsubmit.Click;
```

What happens then is that as soon as you click OK on the message box, the event handler is re-entered because you called `btnsubmit.Click` and so the whole routine starts again. And the message box is shown, and you press OK and then `btnsubmit.Click` is called again and so on. If you have enough patience you should be able to get a stack overflow error!

Comment: +1 for your prophetic abilities, I don't have enough patience to take my crystal ball and read this code to the end :)

Comment: I think david should sell his "brain delphi compiler" to Embarcadero. :)

Comment: +1 for, just, 'rather gruesome event handler'  It's a pity about the date - it would have won last years 'Gruesome Event Handler' competition.  Now there is another year for some developer to beat it :)  Well, OK, maybe the point for the recursion issue...

Comment: Now that's some spaghetti code! +1 for reading the code till the end :)